# Javascript closure inside function doesn't "remember" it's environment

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, closures

I have a function, which retrieves data from the database and passes it to callback. For optimization purposes I want this data to be updated at most once per 60 seconds. My closure function looks like:

```
function delayedUpdate(fn, delay, callback) {
  var nextCall = Date.now();
  var data = false;

  (function () {
    if (nextCall <= Date.now()) {
      nextCall = Date.now() + delay;
      fn(function (err, res) {
        data = err ? false : res;
        callback(err, data);
      });
    } else {
      callback(null, data);
    }
  })();
}
```

I noticed that when I "construct" this function in my desired funtion, which is called very often I'm basically creating a closure in loop, so it has no chance to work properly:

```
function update()
{
  delayedUpdate(server.getDbData, 60000, function (err, data) {
    someDataToRender = data;
  });
}
```

Wrapping `delayedUpdate` in other function and assigning to variable doesn't work aswell. How can I accomplish my goal? I know this might be dumb question, but I'm still learning.

Comment: You're calling your "delayedUpdate" function, but you're not paying any attention to the returned function.  It'll return that function, your code ignores it, so nothing will ever happen.

Comment: I've messed up. I had an IIFE instead of returning a function. Edited it.

Comment: OK, so with the IIFE the code in that inner function will run essentially immediately, and `nextCall` will almost certainly be exactly the same or possibly very slightly less than the current date. There's really no interesting closure involved at all when it's an IIFE, because the inner function invocation is over and done with by the time the outer function returns.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So should I return the function, assign it to variable outside the `update` function's scope and invoke it in the `update`?

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve overall.

Comment: I want to make a function which retrieves data from the server, stores it and passes to callback. When function is called again before delay time it should return the stored data, otherwise it should retrieve the data from the server again, and pass the updated one.

Comment: Apart from [the problem with the context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572), it sounds what you're looking for is [a debounce function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30222791/1048572). But you're using [the wrong approach for that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29697116/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like your *original* code:

```
function delayedUpdate(fn, delay, callback) {
  var nextCall = Date.now();
  var data = false;

  return function () {
    if (nextCall <= Date.now()) {
      nextCall = Date.now() + delay;
      fn(function (err, res) {
        data = err ? false : res;
        callback(err, data);
      });
    } else {
      callback(null, data);
    }
  };
}
```

Then your `update` function would be:

```
var update = delayedUpdate((server.getDbData, 60000, function (err, data) {
  someDataToRender = data;
});
```

That is, `update` is the function returned from calling `delayedUpdate`. When you call `update`, it will do that timestamp check.

One thing to note: that `getDbData` function might not like being called without the context of that `server` object, whatever it is. If so, then the setup should look like:

```
var update = delayedUpdate((server.getDbData.bind(server), 60000, function (err, data) {
  someDataToRender = data;
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to `.bind(server)`

Comment: @Bergi ha ha just added that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. You just need to declare the variables `nextCall` and `data` outside of the function:

```
var nextCall = Date.now();
var data = false;

function delayedUpdate(fn, delay, callback) {

    if (nextCall <= Date.now()) {

        nextCall = Date.now() + delay;

        fn(function (err, res) {
            data = err ? false : res;
            callback(err, data);
        });
    } else {
        callback(null, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pointy How about the first line in the `if` block?